# Override an existing Blade directive

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I'm building a system that implements an inherited template system using Blade.  Depending on where the user is, a different view will be loaded.

The system works well, where I have a default 'theme', which contains all views and components for everything the website uses.  I don't use the default `view` method in my controllers, I instead use my own function which works in the same way as `view` but instead attempts to load the view in the lowest part of the hierarchy and then works its way up until it lands on the default.

For example, my view structure looks like:

```
+-- views
|   +-- frontend
|      +-- default
|         +-- home.blade.php
|         +-- test.blade.php
|      +-- site1
|         +-- en-gb
|             +-- home.blade.php
|         +-- en-de 
|             +-- home.blade.php 
|      +-- site2
|         +-- en-gb 
|             +-- home.blade.php
```

This works well.  I can call `custom_view('home');` and based on certain circumstances the correct view will be shown.  In the above example if I call `custom_view('test')` my system will check the correct folder for the site and locale, and if the view doesn't exist then the default fallback will be used.

My problem comes when I want to use Laravel directives for loading view partials in my code.  The three directives that are troublesome are:

`@each()`, `@include()` and `@component()`.

I would like to override these directives and have them look up the file from the appropriate sub-directory in my view structure first.

How can I override Blade directives?

Comment: Look into the `includeIf` and `includeWhen` directives for loading views and partials

Comment: I'm not sure what good that would do?  This is about automatic inheritance, unless I'm missing something?